# Database Search Query to show as Links

Tags: php, sql, search, search-engine

I am pretty new to php and I am developing a website with a search bar.

I have used some code to implement a search query to search for products from my database. The search query works fines and displays all the required products which need to be displayed.

However, I want the items to have a link to the product details page which shows more information about that specific product. However, I do not have a clue how you would represent this as a link using html.

My search code is as follows:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$search_output = "";
if(isset($_POST['searchquery']) && $_POST['searchquery'] != ""){
    $searchquery = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9?]#i', '', $_POST['searchquery']);
    if($_POST['filter1'] == "Food"){
        $sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE pd_name LIKE '%$searchquery%'";
    }
    include_once("config.php");


    //Database connections below


     mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass) or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db($dbName) or die(mysql_error());

    $query = mysql_query($sqlCommand) or die(mysql_error());
    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($count >= 1){
        $search_output .= "<hr />$count results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
            $pd_name = $row["pd_name"];
        $search_output .= "$pd_name<br />";
        } // close while
    } else {
        $search_output = "<hr />0 results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />";
    }
}
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
Search for dishes : 
  <input name="searchquery" type="text" size="30" maxlength="100"> 
In: 
<select name="filter1">
<option value="Food">Food</option>

</select>
<input name="myBtn" type="submit" value="Search">

<br />
</form>
<div>
<?php echo $search_output; ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The link I want it to reference to is:

```
<a href="" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?c=$catId&p=$pd_id" . "">$pd_name</a>
```

However, when adding this reference, it does not seem to work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try switching this:

```
$pd_name = $row["pd_name"];
$search_output .= "$pd_name<br />";
```

With this:

```
$pd_name = $row["pd_name"];
$pd_id   = $row["pd_id"];
$search_output .= '<a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '"?c=$catId&p=' . $pd_id . '">' . $pd_name . '</a><br>';
```

By the way, you need to read up on SQL injections as you should be escaping user input data before passing it to the database. At least change this:

```
$sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE pd_name LIKE '%$searchquery%'";
```

To this:

```
$sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE pd_name LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($searchquery)."%'";
```

Comment: I guess his `preg_replace()` would cover it. But I would think escaping the information would be automatic anyway just to be sure. No?

Comment: escaping has noting to do with safety. one have to escape strings, not whatever "information". not because of whatever "injections" but because of SQL syntax rules. The string is already formatted - so, no need to format it again. If it were really automated, using some sort of placeholder hiding the actual escaping - yes, it have to be done. But escaping just for sake of escaping is but a superstition.

Comment: Thanks guys, appreciate the help. I have now got it working by declaring all the necessary variables.